# IntelliJ IDEA failed to start

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14 everything worked fine, but somehow it doesn't work anymore the error I get is:

[image: image error]

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old bug triggered by a race condition in some cases:

- [IDEA-149135](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149135) Startup with splash screen fails (ServiceManager.doGetService must not be null)

You should update to the current IDE version or [try the workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149135#comment=27-1265441).

Comment: i took a look to the workaround seems the problem is with jdk 6 actually i was working with java 8 but the project i'm working on now requires java 6 when i changed it still worked but after that it crashes everytime i now changed to java 8 but still same error guess the only alternative now is to update the version, hope the new version will work fine with java 6